# Line that returns to the same point using XY To Line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, arcgis-10.7, data-management

I am using XY To Line in ArcMap 10.7 to project the direction a fish swims between acoustic receivers (points). There are instances where the fish swims away from a point and back to the same point. Of course, these lines do not show on the map when using XY To Line.

Is there a way to project them in ArcMap, for example, as a line that loops away from the point and comes back again like a circle?

In the screenshot below, I have manually added the sort of line I would like to achieve.

[image: Line going from and to the same point on the map]

Comment: I think Points to Line geoprocessing tool shall do the trick. You may provide a screenshot/info on how this circular routes are identified in your data (are they a set of coordinates!!)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. Briefly, if a fish is not detected for a set amount of time it is considered to have left the area. If it returns to the same location as it was last detected, I want to show it as the above loop. The data just has start lat/long and end lat/long.

Comment: I see, Points to line would not do the work in this case. The manual circular direction you added sounds a good way to go unless you have a big number of points. In this case, one daunting way around it is to isolate the points by attributes (where Xstart=Xend & Ystart=Yend) then make a buffer around them. To make the buffer rings as circular directions, you can then select all the rings and move them at once to make the circumference of one ring touch its origin point. Then you can break the rings by the points to make them polylines and merge the new layer with the original direction layer.

Comment: Such fake will only add uncertainties to already noisy data.

Comment: I agree with @FelixIP, such manipulation would be acceptable only if the purpose is around visualization (and I suppose there will be better way to achieve it as well). In all cases, such supposed routes for movement around points would introduce uncertainty no matter how it's produced, unless you have a very good reason for assuming such case and maybe some specific restriction on this movement as well!